# Adjusting Wordpress Max Execution time for Dashboard Only, but excluding admin-ajax

Tags: php, wordpress

My WP dashboard is painfully slow.  I've looked into it and have followed all of the steps to speed it up, and have not had much luck.

I am pretty sure the slowness is attributed to woocommerce alone, so maybe there is someway to apply a different max execution time, but only when woocommerce is being loaded?

So, I am curious if it is somehow possible to increase the max_execution_time only for the wp dashboard.

I considered putting an htaccess file into the wp-admin/ directory, but I assume that would increase the execution time for any and all calls to wp-admin including wp-admin/admin-ajax which is used by much more than only the dashboard.

I know I can put an inline max_execution_time call in my code somewhere, but I don't want to necessarily open everything up only because it is just limited to the admin area.  Everything else loads very quickly and I haven't figured out how to say, "Hey wordpress... can you only bump this up if we are in the ACTUAL dashboard?"

Currently I am just setting the global setting manually when I need to go into the dashboard to prevent timeouts.

Something like:

```
if($the_actual_dashboard_is_being_displayed) {
    ini_set('max_execution_time', '300'); 
}
```

Comment: How about `if( is_admin() && !wp_doing_ajax() )` ?

Comment: @MosheGross Will try this.  I suppose just put it in functions.php?